# My PC started blue screening. How do I troubleshoot it?

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, bsod

Several weeks ago, my laptop started displaying the Blue Screen.  First it was perhaps once a day, so I just lived with it but as of 3 days ago, it happens roughly an hour after I log in.

As you can see from the reliability app, it started on 5/12/2021.
[image]

When I look in the details of the problem in the Reliability app for the Hardware Error entry, the problem is `LiveKernelEvent`, code `ab`.

[image]

When I double click on "Shut down unexpectedly", I get BlueScreen, code `ca`.

[image]

The Stop Code on the Blue Screen itself is always REFERENCE_BY_POINTER.

[image]

I googled around for these values, but didn't get anything definitive.

So I figured some driver must have gotten installed on 5/12/2021.  So I headed to Windows Update/View Update History.  The last thing under `Driver Updates` was installed 2 months prior to blue screen issues.  So it can't be that.  I also looked at other Windows Update entries and there was `KB4023057: Update for Windows 10 Update Service components`, but it was installed 4/29/2021, so that can't be it either.

I then investigated Apps & Features to see if any app got installed around the time of the problem, and got some apps that, I suppose, could be suspicious.

[image]

Finally, I went to the Dell Utility and had it run its Driver scan and it offered to install 1GB worth of updates, which I allowed.  I was hopeful because it included BIOS updates.  Nonetheless, the laptop still blue screened after an hour of work.

I perused the Event Viewer, but found nothing suspicious.  I then ran `Memtest64`, which found no issues.  `ChkDsk` didn't either.  `sfc /scannow` didn't either.    My next step is to upgrade from v 20H2 to 21H1 and but I am not holding out much hope for that.

What else can I do to troubleshoot the blue screens?

P.S. My attempt to upgrade latest version of Windows (21H1) has failed.  Something there triggers this same BlueScreen between 80 to 85% of the installation.